# contact form emailed using php

Tags: php, html

I am trying to get myContact Us form on my web project to work with php so that when the full name and email address is entered with comments it sends me an email and then displays a success message and if they fail to fill in the form them an error message displays saying for them to try again.  My code is not working and I dont really understand why, it just displays with error message no matter what even when all info is entered.  this is my php code below: -

```
`<?php`

$name = $email = "";

if (isset ($_POST ['fullname']))
    $name = fix_string ($_POST ['fullname']);
    if (isset ($_POST ['email'])) $email = fix_string ($_POST ['email']);

    $email_to = "my@eamiladdress.com";

    $email_subject = "Question asked";

    echo "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN'
        'http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd'>
        <html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xml:lang='en'>
            <head>
                <link href='myelearningtool.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
                <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8' />
                <title>Registration Confirmation E-Learning Tool Prototype</title>
                <div class='page'>
                    <div class='header'>
                        <div id='logo'>
                            <img src='images/BS_kids_ELearningToollogo.png' alt='E-Learning Tool Prototype v1' />
                        </div>
                        <ul id='navigation'>
                            <li><a href='****************.html'>Logout</a></li>
                            <li><a href='**************.html'>Activities</a></li>
                            <li><a href='****************.html'>Videos</a></li>
                            <li><a href='****************.html'>Glossary</a></li>
                            <li><a href='********'>Contact Us</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div><!--end of header div -->
                    <div class='content'><!--start of content -->
                        <div class='contact_details'>
                            <p>Thanks for that, someone will email you back as soon as possible.</P>
                            </div><!--end of contact details-->
                        </div>
                    </div><!--end of content div-->
                </div>
            </div>
        </html>"; 

$fail  = validate_fullname($name);
$fail += validate_email($email);

if ($fail == ""){
    echo "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN'
        'http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd'>
        <html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xml:lang='en'>
            <head>
                <link href='myelearningtool.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
                <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8' />
                <title>Registration Confirmation E-Learning Tool Prototype</title>
                <div class='page'>
                    <div class='header'>
                        <div id='logo'>
                            <img src='images/BS_kids_ELearningToollogo.png' alt='E-Learning Tool Prototype v1' />
                        </div>
                        <ul id='navigation'>
                            <li><a href='****************.html'>Return To Home Page</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div><!--end of header div -->
                    <div class='content'><!--start of content -->
                        <p>Ooops yous missed something off.  Please try again</p>
                        <fieldset><!--details section-->
                            <legend><b>Contact Us</b></legend>
                            <label for='name'> Your Full Name*:</label> <input type='text' name='fullname' id='name' maxlength='50' size='30' tabindex='1' accesskey='q' />
                            <label for='email'>Email Address*:</label><input type='text' name='email' id='email' maxlength='50' size='30' tabindex='2' accesskey='w' />
                        </fieldset><!--end of fieldset-->
                    <div class='message'>
                        <fieldset>
                            <legend>Message*</legend>
                            <textarea name='message' id='msge' cols='130' rows='10'>Please type your question or query here</textarea>
                        </fieldset>
                        <p><input type='submit' value='Enter' /></p>
                    </div><!--end of content div-->
                </div>
            </div>
        </html>";
}

function validate_fullname($name){
    return ($name == "")? "No name was entered<br>": "";
}
function validate_email($email){
    if ($email == "")
        return "No email was entered<br>";
    else if (!((strpos($email, ".") > 0) && (strpos($email, "@") > 0)) || preg_match ("/[^a-z A-Z 0-9.@_-]/", $email))
        return "The Email address is invalid<br>";
    return "";
}
function fix_string($string){
    if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) $string = stripslashes($string);
        return htmlentities ($string);
}

?>
```

Can anyone please help me and advise on where I am going wrong.

I have made some changes to my code as suggested.  I am at a loss I not really understanding why it isnt working, it is also not using the css style sheet.  below is the new edited code: -

```
<?php

    if (isset($_POST ['fullname']) || isset($_POST ['email'])):
        $name = fix_string($_POST ['fullname']);
        $email = fix_string($_POST ['email']);

        $email_to = "my@email.com";
        $email_subject = "My E-Learning Tool Query";

        $fail  = validate_fullname($name);
        $fail += validate_email($email);

        if($fail!=""):
?>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN'
    'http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd'>
    <html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xml:lang='en'>
        <head>
            <link href='myelearningtool.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
            <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8' />
            <title>Contact Us E-Learning Tool Prototype</title>
            <div class='page'>
                <div class='header'>
                    <div id='logo'>
                        <img src='images/BS_kids_ELearningToollogo.png' alt='E-Learning Tool Prototype v1' />
                    </div>
                    <ul id='navigation'>
                        <li><a href='http://******/myelearningtool.html'>Return To Home Page</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div><!--end of header div -->
                <div class='ContactUs'><!--start of content -->
                    <p>Ooops yous missed something off.  Please try again</p>
                    <form method='post' action='php/contactUs.php' onsubmit='return validation(this)' ><!-- Start of the form to be submitted -->
                        <fieldset><!--details section-->
                            <legend><b>Contact Us</b></legend>
                            <label for='name'> Your Full Name*:</label> <input type='text' name='fullname' id='name' maxlength='50' size='30' tabindex='1' accesskey='q' />
                            <label for='email'>Email Address*:</label><input type='text' name='email' id='email' maxlength='50' size='30' tabindex='2' accesskey='w' />
                        </fieldset><!--end of fieldset-->
                    <div class='message'>
                        <fieldset>
                            <legend>Message*</legend>
                            <textarea name='message' id='msge' cols='130' rows='10'>Please type your question or query here</textarea>
                        </fieldset>
                        <p><input type='submit' value='Enter' /></p>
                    </div>
                </div><!--end of contact us div-->
            </div>
        </div>
    </html>
<?php 
    else:
?>      
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN'
    'http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd'>
    <html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xml:lang='en'>
        <head>
            <link href='myelearningtool.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
            <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8' />
            <title>Registration Confirmation E-Learning Tool Prototype</title>
            <div class='page'>
                <div class='header'>
                    <div id='logo'>
                        <img src='images/BS_kids_ELearningToollogo.png' alt='E-Learning Tool Prototype v1' />
                    </div>
                    <ul id='navigation'>
                        <li><a href='http://******myelearningtool.html'>Logout</a></li>
                        <li><a href='http://******/myelearningtoolactivities.html'>Activities</a></li>
                        <li><a href='http://******t/myelearningtoolVideos.html'>Videos</a></li>
                        <li><a href='http://******t/myelearningtoolglossary.html'>Glossary</a></li>
                        <li><a href=' '>Contact Us</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div><!--end of header div -->
                <div class='content'><!--start of content -->
                    <div class='ContactUs'>
                        <p>Thanks for that, someone will email you back as soon as possible.</P>
                    </div><!--end of contact us-->
                </div><!--end of content div-->
            </div>
        </div>
    </html>
<?php
    endif;
?>

<?php 
    else:
?>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">

    <head>
        <link href="myelearningtool.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Contact Us Page for e-Learning Tool Prototype</title><!--this is the title of the page, I have chosen this title as it states exactly what the web page is -->
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="page">
            <div class="header"><!--start of the header which will contain the banner and navigation-->
                <ul id="navigation" style="text-align: center">
                    <li><a href="http://******/myelearningtool.html">Home Page</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Activites</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Videos</a></li>
                </ul>
                <div id="logo" style="text-align: center">
                    <img src="images/BS_kids_ELearningToollogo.png" alt="E-Learning Tool Prototype v1" /><!--logo created in photoshop-->
                </div><!--end of logo div-->
            </div><!--end of header div -->
            <div class="ContactUs">
                <form method="post" action="php/contactUs.php" onsubmit="return validation(this)" ><!-- Start of the form to be submitted -->
                    <fieldset><!--details section-->
                        <legend><b>Contact Us</b></legend>
                        <label for="name"> Your Full Name*:</label> <input type="text" name="fullname" id="name" maxlength="100" size="30" tabindex="1" accesskey="q" />
                        <label for="email">Email Address*:</label><input type="text" name="email" id="email" maxlength="50" size="30" tabindex="2" accesskey="w" />
                    </fieldset><!--end of fieldset-->
                    <div class="message">
                        <fieldset>
                            <legend>Message*</legend>
                            <textarea name="message" id="msge" cols="130" rows="10">Please type your question or query here</textarea>
                        </fieldset>
                        <p><input type="submit" value="Enter" /></p>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div><!--end of div-->
        </div><!--end of page div-->
    </body><!--end of body div-->
</html><!--end of html div-->

<?php

endif;



    $fail  = validate_fullname($name);
    $fail += validate_email($email);

function validate_fullname($name){
    return ($name == "")? "No name was entered<br>": "";
}
function validate_email($email){
    if ($email == "")
        return "No email was entered<br>";
    else if (!((strpos($email, ".") > 0) && (strpos($email, "@") > 0)) || preg_match ("/[^a-z A-Z 0-9.@_-]/", $email))
        return "The Email address is invalid<br>";
    return "";
}
function fix_string($string){
    if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) $string = stripslashes($string);
        return htmlentities ($string);
}

?>
```

Comment: What error message is it displaying?

Comment: First problem I see is that you don't have a `form` tag anywhere in your html

Comment: It also seems like you may have an issue with your first if statements, I'm assuming you only want the first block of html to show up if the form has been submitted?

Comment: @WheatBeak thank never noticed that about the form tag. and yes I only want the first block of html to show up when the form is submitted correctly and the second block if there is an error and something was missing.  At the moment I am just getting both blocks of html echoed back to my page and no email sent

Comment: You also need a few more conditionals in there.  You should have 3 scenarios 1) someone has come to the page normally 2) someone has submitted the form properly 3) someone has submitted the form with errors

Comment: @WheatBeak  I have normal HTML contact us page with the form to be submitted calling my PHP. Then the PHP I have got the above code, which incorrect at the moment.I have corrected some missing </div> In the PHP if statements 1) you have mentioned someone has come to the page normally (I'm sorry don't understand this)  2) the form is submitted properly and message displays saying success and echos the page with navigation bar and finally 3) form submitted in correctly and PHP echos error message and form to correct this and resubmit.

Comment: what I meant by 'normally' was viewing the page for the first time, without submitting the form. So you would see the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**

The problem was so small I missed it,

you need to use `.=` not `+=`

```
$fail  = validate_fullname($name);
$fail .= validate_email($email);
```

also remove the second occurrence of that code from the bottom.

and close the form tag on your first block of html

--original answer--

Aside from missing the `form` tag, you can rewrite your if statements using a different sytnax, this allows you to type out html normally without having to echo it.

Work around this example and it should work for you.

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST ['fullname']) || isset($_POST ['email'])):
    $name = fix_string($_POST ['fullname']);
    $email = fix_string($_POST ['email']);

    $email_to = "my@eamiladdress.com";
    $email_subject = "Question asked";

    $fail  = validate_fullname($name);
    $fail .= validate_email($email);

    if($fail!=""):
?>
    <!--Your error html-->
<?php 
    else:
?>
    <!--Your success html-->
<?php
    endif;
?>

<?php 
else:
?>

<!--Your form html-->

<?php
endif;

//Your functions

?>
```

Comment: all I'm getting now is the first message of success.  Can I input the code that I am using?  and you might be able to see where I've gone wrong?  where should I upload, edit my question with the new code?

Comment: yes this seems to be working now, I am getting the correct response.  Can you explain why to use the .=  It doesnt seem to be sending an email or using my CSS style sheet so you know any reason as to why this is?

Comment: Not sure why it's not using the stylesheet, check your paths.  As for sending the mail you'll need to use php's mail function, provided your server supports it.  It's pretty easy to learn, google a tutorial, here's the official documentation http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: I will check that out thank you.  Glad its working now - thanks for the help.